# Firefox addon to hide/display bookmarks toolbar on demand

Tags: firefox, browser-extension

Right now, I'm using Firefox 117 on MacOs Ventura 13.4.1c and I would need an add-on which could hide/display on click the bookmarks toolbar ... can you recommend any extension for this?

Why: sometimes I need as much real estate as possible for certain webpages and this toolbar just wastes space; sometimes, I'm in the middle of something and need to open a certain bookmark ... and it would be way faster if the toolbar was already displayed.

Comment: I'm using FireFox 117 on Windows, and there's a built-in shortcut to show/hide the toolbar, which is Ctrl+Shift+B. I don't currently have a MacOS machine to test with, but I think it could be something similar.

Comment: Thank you @AminDodin. Command+Shift+B is the equivalent on my MacOs and Firefox versions and it does the job. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, but if you want, you could add your comment as a response

Comment: I think the question no longer qualifies as a "software recommendation", and neither you nor I have enough reputation to move it, so I will flag it and ask moderators to move it to Super User, where it can be answered.

Comment: That's fine with me. I have one note though: there are websites where the shortcut doesn't work, so maybe, someday, a plugin will appear doing this ... or maybe not :D

Comment: @radui I'll leave it up to you and what you prefer.  If you like, we can migrate your question to Super User.  Otherwise, it can be left here without a problem.  We actually have quite a few answers where people find non-software-recommendation solutions to questions, and that's totally acceptable.  You can also edit this question to explicitly request an extension that works on sites where the native browser functionality doesn't work.